# How to implement loader/spinner in React Modal?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, spinner

I am trying to implement loader/spinner animation after clicking modal button. I am using Bootstrap Modal.

Basically on clicking button it loads a google form but it remains blank for few seconds. So I want to implement spinner for that.

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import '../components/GoogleForm.css';
function Modal1() {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
   <>

<button className="bg-orange-500 text-white active:bg-orange-600 font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-2 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150" 
  onClick={handleShow} >
    Form
  </button>
    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
       <iframe 
          src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdRvkojp- 
          eopwHU6TnOFDnJccJVgFtjmYaTmKyq_7FOt3R1_w/viewform? 
          embedded=true" 
          width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" 
          marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
       </iframe>
    </Modal.Body>
  </Modal>
</>
  );
}
export default Modal1;
```

[image]
This is how form loads after the modal button (Form) is clicked, but it takes few seconds to load, so want to implement loader/spinner animation till form is loaded

Comment: Can you please share your code so that the community can help you out?